# Telethon: Response from a send_message() gives "Message is not iterable" error when being iterated

Tags: python, iterable, telethon

I am using python and replying to a message using this code in telethon:

```
    s = client.send_message(entity='group', message='Thank you!', reply_to=chatid)
    print(s)
```

And get the response well printed:

```
    Message(id=34535, peer_id=PeerUser(user_id=55455544), date=datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 10, 6, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), # and so on...
```

I can clearly see the output well but the error is there when I try to iterate over it.
However, when I tried looping over the response variable `s` using this:

```
    message_id = []
    message = []
    sender = []
    for chat in s:
        message_id.append(chat.id)
        message.append(chat.message)
        sender.append(chat.from_id)
```

I get this error:

```
    TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to fix this error? Or a workaround?
I want to get the chatid from the response and store it in a variable. Thank you for giving time to read my question!

Comment: What is the output from ```print(s)```?

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate the `Message` object.

If you want to get properties of the `Message` object, do it this way

```
s = client.send_message(entity='group', message='Thank you!', reply_to=chatid)
message_id = []
message = []
sender = []

message_id.append(s.id)
message.append(s.message)
sender.append(s.from_id)
```